# css flexbox child's child element with percentage height

Tags: css, flexbox

Is it possible to use flexbox to have a div that will fill the entire remaining area (using `flex-grow: 1`) and have its' child div dimensions in percentages?

I tried:

```
<div style="height:700px; width 100%; display:flex; flex-direction: column; background-color:red;">
   <div>Hello Plunker!</div>
   <div style="background-color:green; flex-grow:1;">
      <div style="background-color: blue; height:70%; width:70%;"></div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Is flexbox the right way to achieve this?

Comment: Yes, it's possible. Did you try it? Your code seems to work as desired.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's entirely possible as mentioned in [**this question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21126473/percentage-height-in-nested-flex-box)

You just need to specific a height of 100% for the child (holding the grandchild element)

[**JSfiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/qn016dp0/1/)

```
.child {
    background-color:green; 
    flex-grow:1;
    height: 100%;
}
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.parent {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
.child {
  background-color: green;
  flex-grow: 1;
  height: 100%;
}
.g-child {
  background: blue;
  height: 70%;
  width:70%;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div>Hello Plunker!</div>
  <div class="child">
    <div class="g-child"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. do i still need 'flex-grow:1' if i state that 'height:100%'?

Answer (score 0):

Needed to set the parent div as 'position:relative;' and the child as 'position:absolute;'

```
<div style="height:700px; width 100%; display:flex; flex-direction: column; background-color:red;">
      <div>Hello Plunker!</div>
      <div style="background-color:green; flex-grow:1; position:relative;">
          <div style="background-color: blue; position:absolute; height:100%; width:100%;"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: This really doesn't answer how to do this using **flexbox**

Comment: @Paulie_D why not? the outer div is set to 'display: flex'

Comment: But that's not what your answer is...your answer is **positioning** not flexbox.

Comment: @Paulie_D the problem was that the most-inner div (blue) was invisible (height=0) when the most-outer div (red) was set as 'display:flex'. the positioning is the way I found to make it behave as wanted.