# Div with 100% height overflowing body in Chrome

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to make 100% height flex's child as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21165514/656449) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20959601/656449) . In firefox and IE it's shown as expected, but in chrome it's messed up. The divs are getting out of the body. Is it yet another side effect of chrome following the spec to the tee or still a bug?

The code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
    html, body {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
    div {
        border: 1px solid black;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }

    .red-border {
        border: 2px solid red;
    }

    .blue-border {
        border: 2px solid blue;
    }

    .green-border {
        border: 2px solid green;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body class="red-border" >
<div clsas="blue-border" style="display: flex; flex-direction: column; width: 100%; height: 100%;">
    <div  style="flex: 0 1 auto; ">top</content></div>

    <div class="green-border"  style="flex: 1 1 auto; display: flex; flex-direction: row; width: 100%; height: 100%;" >
        <div style="flex: 0 1 auto; ">left</div>
        <div style="flex: 1 1 auto; width: 100%; height: 100%;">
            <div style="background-color: #ff6500; width: 100%; height: 100%;">center</div>
        </div>
        <div style="flex: 0 1 auto; ">right</div>
    </div>

    <div style="flex: 0 1 auto; ">bottom</content></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

plnkr: http://run.plnkr.co/plunks/wi5MQYK5yEdzdgQBaUWh/

that's how it looks in ff and ie (11):
[image: that's how it looks in ff]

that's how it looks in chome:
[image: that's how it looks in chome]

UPDATE:  The 'center' div should be a non-flex div and still have to have 100% height. The reason is to have non-flex div is that my real site structure is quite complicated - it uses a lot of webcomponents and some of them just can't use flex. So at some point I have to stop using flex and have 'normal' div to have height 100%.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem seems to stem from the fact that you're combining both the `height` and `flex-basis` properties in the same declaration block. It appears to create a conflict. In my answer below I've removed the heights and used `flex-basis` instead. You'll note a couple of other adjustments, as well.

---

**Change:**

(1)

`<div class="green-border"
 style="flex: 1 1 auto; display: flex; flex-direction: row; width: 100%; height: 100%;" >`

TO

`<div class="green-border"
style="flex: 1 1 100%; display: flex; flex-direction: row; width: 100%;" >`

*notes: removed `height`; used `flex-basis` instead;*

---

(2)

`<div style="flex: 1 1 auto; width: 100%; height: 100%;">`

TO

`<div style="flex: 1 1 100%; width: 100%; display: flex;">`

*notes: removed `height`; used `flex-basis` instead; established nested flex container;*

---

(3)

`<div style="background-color: #ff6500; width: 100%; height: 100%;">center</div>`

TO

`<div style="background-color: #ff6500; width: 100%; flex: 1 1 100%;">center</div>`

*notes: removed `height`; used `flex-basis` instead; added `flex` property;*

---

Lastly, the blue border wasn't showing due to a typo.

(4)

`clsas="blue-border"`

TO

`class="blue-border"`

---

With the adjustments above, the layout renders in Chrome like this:

[image]

All boxes lie within their containers.

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/0099nrfd/)

---

#### Applying 100% height to nested, non-flex elements

In most cases, when using percentage heights on child elements, a percentage height must also be specified for the parent element and all ancestor elements, up to and including the root element.

```
html, body { height: 100%; }
```

I have explained the reason for this here:

- [Working with the CSS `height` property and percentage values](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31728799/3597276)

But a close look at the [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#propdef-height) reveals an exception:

> The percentage is calculated with respect to the height of the
>   generated box's containing block. If the height of the containing
>   block is not specified explicitly (i.e., it depends on content
>   height), and this element is not absolutely positioned, the value
>   computes to 'auto'.

Note the part: *... and the element is not absolutely positioned.*

Hence, try this on the "center" box:

**Change:**

(5)

```
<div style="background-color: #ff6500; width: 100%; flex: 1 1 100%;">center</div>
```

TO

```
<div style="background-color: #ff6500; width: 100%; flex: 1 1 100%; position: relative;">
    <div style="border: 5px solid yellow; position: absolute; height: 100%; width: 100%;">
       center</div>
</div>
```

Notes:

- added `position: relative` to establish nearest positioned ancestor for absolute positioning
- created new, nested, non-flex `div` container
- applied absolute positioning to new `div` with `height: 100%`.

With absolute positioning you do not need to apply percentage heights to parent containers.

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/0099nrfd/1/)

Comment: Thank you very much for helping!

Comment: But my problem is that I need to get non-flex div to have 100% height. I see that my question isn't clear enough about this. Sorry. The reason is to have non-flex div is that my real site structure is quite complicated - it uses a lot of webcomponents and some of them just can't use flex. So at some point I have to stop using flex and have 'normal' div to have hight 100%. And to get it working I need all parent divs have  hight set in  % or something. From the second links: " Percentages however are calculated from the specified value of the parent's cross-size property, not it's used value."

Comment: You can always nest divs within flex items.

Comment: well, yes, I can, but if my parent (flex) div doesn't have height set its childrens heights set in % will be useless. Am I wrong?

Comment: You are not wrong, but there is an exception to that rule. See my revised answer.

Comment: yes!  sample works pefectly, but still can't get my real app working... looks like those relative/absolut positions break some component. And getting back to the original question: do you think that inability to correctly handle  flex div with height is a bug in chrome? Or there is something in spec which prohibits setting height on flex divs?

Comment: Like you wrote in your revision, your site structure is complex. So maybe there's something in there you need to debug. In terms of the behavior between browsers, I'm not sure it's a bug and haven't seen anything about conflicts between heights and `flex-basis`. There may be something in the standard, I just haven't run into it yet. Or it may be yet another difference in interpretation between browsers. I've been seeing a lot of that lately: See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32911324/3597276) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32885534/3597276).

Answer (score -2):

The problem is that your border makes the div larger than 100%, causing it to pop out. Try making your child div smaller than 100%, like 99%. That should resolve your issue.

Comment: thank you for suggesting!, I've tried, but it doesn't seem to have any effect - the bottom thing sticks out way beyond border width. And there is  box-sizing: border-box;...

Comment: Try 98% or 97%. If that doesn't work, try float:left and display:block.